# Deriving formula for asymptotes of a hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find a precalculus-level derivation of the formula for the asymptotes of a hyperbola. My book says:

> Solving $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$
>
> for $y$, we obtain
>
> $y = \pm \frac ba \sqrt{x^2 - a^2}$
>
> $ = \pm \frac ba \sqrt{x^2(1 - \frac {a^2}{x^2})}$
>
> $ = \pm \frac bax \sqrt{(1 - \frac {a^2}{x^2})}$

then goes on to say $\frac {a^2}{x^2}$ approaches 0, and therefore the asymptotes are at $y = \pm \frac ba x$

However, in my attempt to derive the formula, I have been unable to get to the first equation. I got as far as
$y^2 = -b^2(1 - \frac {x^2}{a^2})$

Comment: $y^2=-b^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})=\frac{b^2}{a^2}(x^2-a^2)$. When you take the square root, you need to account for both + and - $\frac{b}{a}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$y^2=-b^2\left(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)$$

$$y^2=\frac{b^2}{a^2}(x^2-a^2)\tag{factor $1/a^2$ out}$$

$$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}(x^2-a^2)}$$

$$y=\pm\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$$